# What is the Angular 2 Lifecycle equivalent of $postLink?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-upgrade

I'm currently upgrading from Angular.JS (1.5) to Angular 2+. I have come across as `$postLink` method in an `IComponentController` and I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent lifecycle hook is in Angular 2+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most probably looking for `ngAfterViewInit` which fires after component and all its child components are initialized.

Of course, it depends on your particular use case as with async data loading there might be some discrepancies which might be needed to be handled differently (for example, monitoring async changes on @Input() properties, but that's another topic).

doc ref:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Comment: That seems to make sense. My `Input`s don't have async changes on them, but thanks for raising that concern!

Comment: you're welcome. Just to complete ref, monitoring changes on `@Inputs` is being done through `OnChanges` hook (documented on same link).

Answer (score 4):

It would be `ngAfterViewInit`.

`$postLink` in [AngularJS](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#using-postlink):

> We are essentially notified by the hook once all child elements are linked and ready to go

`ngAfterViewInit` in [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views.